# How can I find the first and last occurrence of similar elements in a multidimensional array based on 2 criteria elements in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [event] => Array
        (
            [group] => 1
            [name] => Meetings
            [time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [room] => A
                            [label] => Meeting 100
                            [start] => 2016-09-07T14:30:00-04:00
                            [end] => 2016-09-07T15:00:00-04:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [room] => A
                            [label] => Meeting 100
                            [booking_start] => 2016-09-07T15:00:00-04:00
                            [booking_end] => 2016-09-07T15:30:00-04:00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [room] => A
                            [label] => Meeting 200
                            [booking_start] => 2016-09-07T15:30:00-04:00
                            [booking_end] => 2016-09-07T16:00:00-04:00
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [room] => B
                            [label] => Meeting 300
                            [booking_start] => 2016-09-07T16:00:00-04:00
                            [booking_end] => 2016-09-07T16:30:00-04:00
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [room] => B
                            [label] => Meeting 300
                            [booking_start] => 2016-09-07T16:30:00-04:00
                            [booking_end] => 2016-09-07T17:00:00-04:00
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Each "event->time" has elements listed in 1/2 hour increments, causing Meetings to span one or more arrays.  I'm looking for an efficient way to find the first and last instance of each "time" based on both the "room" and "label" in order to calculate the start and end time of the individual Meetings and return "label", "room", actual start time, and actual end time. Can anyone suggest a method that might work well?

Comment: Erm... what happened to loops and ifs??

Comment: I tried looping and an array_reverse, but it didn't seem all that efficient. I was hoping there might be a more elegant/efficient option.

Comment: Using `array_reverse()` doesn't seem like a good option. Because end time of a 'session' might not always be at the end of an array. Instead you can loop through an array once and group the elements according to their room and label values (push them into arrays) then calculate each group's start/end times.

Comment: 'array_reverse()' was a messy option indeed. I'll give separate arrays a try...thank you!